# How to erase all parts from google doc after specific text using google api scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

The problem is to erase all content paragraphs, images, tables or whatever after some specific text ('#PLACEHOLDER#' in my case). Do I need to loop through all or can I clear everything just after getting the position of range?

```
var body = somedoc.getBody();
var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");
var ele = range.getElement();
if (ele.getParent().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) {
  var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());

}
```

Can I add something like  `body.delteText(offset + 1)`or `body.setText('',offset + 1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to remove all children in the body after the paragraph which is `#PLACEHOLDER#` in the Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Document service is used.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows. In this modification, the script in the if statement is modified.

From:

```
var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
```

To:

```
var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());

// Retrieve total number of children in the body.
var numChildren = body.getNumChildren();

// If the text of the last paragraph is cleared.
body.getChild(numChildren - 1).asParagraph().editAsText().setText("");

// The children from offset to the child before the last paragraph are removed.
for (var i = numChildren - 2; i > offset; i--) {
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(i));
}
```

- In this case, the paragraph of `#PLACEHOLDER#` is not removed. If you want to also remove the paragraph of `#PLACEHOLDER#`, please modify as follows.

  - From: `for (var i = numChildren - 2; i > offset; i--) {`
  - To: `for (var i = numChildren - 2; i >= offset; i--) {`

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Docs API is used. When you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). In this case, the result from `body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#")` is used and the for loop for removing children is not used.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows. In this modification, the script in the if statement is modified.

From:

```
var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
```

To:

```
var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());

// Retrieve document.
var content = Docs.Documents.get(somedoc.getId()).body.content;

// Create request body.
var startIndex = content[offset + 1].paragraph.elements[0].endIndex;
var endIndex = content[content.length - 1].paragraph.elements[0].endIndex - 1;
var resource = {requests: [{deleteContentRange: {range: {startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: endIndex}}}]};

// Update document.
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, somedoc.getId());
```

- In this case, the paragraph of `#PLACEHOLDER#` is not removed. If you want to also remove the paragraph of `#PLACEHOLDER#`, please modify as follows.

  - From: `content[offset + 1].paragraph.elements[0].endIndex`
  - To: `content[offset].paragraph.elements[0].endIndex`

### References:

- [getNumChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getNumChildren())
- [removeChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removechildchild)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.